# What happens when you assign the result of a reduction operator to a multi-bit wire?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog

I may just be having a mental breakdown, but what should be the value of `f` after the following:

```
    wire [3:0] u = 4'b0101;
    wire [3:0] f = |u;
```

Should this not create an error? What am I missing?

Comment: It reduces to a 1-bit result. ORed 4'b0101 reduces to 1, but this should just be placed in the 4-bit holding vector as 4'b0001. Simulate it and see.

Comment: okay, now how about if u = 4'bx001?
It would still reduce to 1, so it would still end up with f = 4'b0001;
right?

Comment: Are you actually getting an error? I thought the | operator is just shorthand for a wire OR and treated no differently than u[0] | u[1] | u[2] | u[3]. If any of your values or 1 or 0, it will evaluate using those values, overriding the undefined bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After simulating in Vivado, I found that the undefined bits are overridden when the | operator is applied to a vector with a 1 in it, and the result 1 is placed in bit 0. If no 1 is detected (only 0 or X), the rest of the vector is returned as 0, but bit 0, the result, is returned as X.

In other words, Verilog, at least in Vivado's implementation, produces:

- |(4'bX010) = 4'b0001
- |(4'bX000) = 4'b000X
- |(4'bXXXX) = 4'b000X

Per your question, no "error" is caused, because these are all defined values of Verilog's wire data type. This result makes sense because a 1 in the input vector must, by definition, OR to produce 1, but since an undefined value could be anything, we can't say for certain what the result is if we're only ORing it with 0s.